# How to handle and test Mongoengine objects with ReferenceField?

Tags: python, json, flask, mongoengine

So,

I'm writing a REST Api with Flask-RESTful, MongoEngine and marshmallow and I'm with some issues on testing my models that have ReferenceFields.

I have a "Praia" model that have a "atividades" ReferenceField.

When I pass

```
class PraiasSerializer(Schema):
  id = fields.String()
  atividades = fields.Nested(AtividadesSerializer, many=True)

  class Meta:
    additional = ('nome', 'descricao')

model = {'nome': 'nome', 'descricao': 'descricao',
          atividades: [ativ1.id, ativ2.id]}
praia = Praias(**model)
data = PraiasSerializer(praia).data
data.pop('id')
self.client.post('/v1/praias', data=data,
                 content_type='application/json')
```

Even with this data.pop('id') to make my model not send 'id' to my controller I receive a `TypeError: add_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

When I print this data variable I get the following output:

```
{u'atividades': [{u'id': u'5501dee0e13823649320299d'}, {u'id': u'5501dee0e13823649320299c'}], u'descricao': u'Portao e sucesso!', u'nome': u'Porto da Barra'}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I've sent a request through Postman to my API and this is working! The problem in my test is id list of dicts coming from the Nested field from marshmallow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer!

I just changed the way I mounted the json data for the post request.

Instead of using my Serializer or json.dumps(Model) I'm using:

```
model = {'nome': 'nome', 'descricao': 'descricao',
          atividades: [str(ativ1['id']), str(ativ2['id'])]}
data = json.dumps(model)
```

I did a cast to str on id because Python doesn't know how to JSON serialize the ObjectId.

Now the request just works!